# SlideToggle Specific Div onClick of Checkbox has yet to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Following this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swQLg/10/ has yet to work with this setup http://jsfiddle.net/u56Zv/

HTML:

```
<div class="PanelWhen" id="PanelWhen">
        That
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn whenBtn">
    <input type="checkbox" id="whenBtn"> When
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#PanelWhen {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#whenBtn").on('click', function () {
        var $when = $(this).next("#PanelWhen");
        $when.slideToggle();
        $("#PanelWhen").not($when).slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @GaryHole The div with 'This' has yet to appear (toggle show)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery, so you have to make sure to include that library in the fiddle.

Secondly, the `.previous` method searches for a sibling element--it doesn't look anywhere in the DOM tree. Note that in the first example, it looks for the `next('.ans')` element--which works fine because all of the elements are siblings.

In your example, you may want to just scope the $when var to be the specific element you want revealed, but if you want a repeatable result across the site, you should think about scoping it with some locative method (i.e. `.parent`, `.children`, `.siblings`, `.next`, `.previous` etc.)

Here's your new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u56Zv/2/

Comment: This works great, except when delivering the buttons using handlebars templating, the toggle no longer works.. any suggestions?

Comment: Can I see your `.handlebars` template?

Comment: Yeh, thanks, here's a fiddle.. The HTML is the .handlebars template.. And the javascript is the ajax that relates, but it won't load in the fiddle (included for transparency).. http://jsfiddle.net/7FwNA/